# How do I retrieve an array from wp_postmeta with get_post_meta?

Tags: array

I have got an array stored in the wp_postmeta table. It is has a meta_key of   `custom_repeatable`  It has a post_id of 6. How do I retrieve this & echo it?  I think I have to use the following, but it isn't working:

`$item = get_post_meta($post->ID, custom_repeatable', false);
 echo $item;`

My array has two names stored in it currently (just learning)

My Question: How do I retrieve the stored array & echo it?

Comment: What kind of array?  Serialized?  json?  Could you post your script that stores the data originally?

Comment: @AndrewBartel Thank-you for taking an interest. it is definitely a serialized array. I will look through my code & pick out the relevant parts.

Comment: Have you read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95336/how-do-i-retrieve-multi-dimensional-arrays-from-the-wp-postmeta-table-display/95415#95415)?

Comment: Looks like @toscho linked an answer for you.