# Access Serialized Post Meta Values

Tags: post-meta

I am using the Humanmade fork of a custom meta box class, they give the ability to set up groups of repeatable fields, as such I have a post saved with post_meta as follows ...

6 meta_id entries in the post_meta table with the same key "course-dates", each of these keys has sub keys and values as serialized data if you will, example as follows ...

a:2:{s:18:"course-dates-start";s:10:"11/25/2013";s:16:"course-dates-end";s:10:"12/20/2013";}

How do I access these individual values or pull them all in and loop over them?

Thank you

*****EDIT*******

Managed the below to get all combinations echoing out, still unsure how to go about accessing specific values ....

```
<?php 
    $dates = get_post_custom ( $post->ID ); 
    $date = $dates['course-dates'];
    foreach ( $date as $d ) {
        $rpt = unserialize( $d );
        echo $rpt['course-dates-start'].' - '.$rpt['course-dates-end'];
        echo '<br/>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95336/how-do-i-retrieve-multi-dimensional-arrays-from-the-wp-postmeta-table-display/95415#95415), set the last parameter for `get_post_meta()` to `FALSE`.

Comment: no that doesn't work and has been tried, I have multiple meta_id with the same key

Comment: Don't use `get_post_custom` unless you absolutely need all the data it will send back to you, instead call `get_post_meta` with the appropriate values and iterate over the returned data(it will also unserialize the data for you if necessary - fyi you shouldn't be serializing it yourself, the functions provided by WP will do that as needed for you).

Comment: I have a very different setup with 6 meta_id entries all with the same key and within them a further 2 serialized key / values. These all belong to the same post as they were created using repeatable groups and fields.

From what I can see Wordpress offers no way of accessing these and unserializing is the only route. 

I stand correcting but WP Query is not going to be able to handle this and I will need to look at another route.