# How do I retrieve a value from a multi - dimensional array using get_post_meta?

Tags: array, post-meta

I know that I need to use 
`get_post_meta(31, $custom_repeatable, true);` The `post_id` is  `31` and the `meta_value` is `$custom_repeatable`. I would like to display the value `hamsters repeat one` only 
. My array:

```
Array  
(  
    [custom_formmessagetype] => Array  
    (  
        [0] => hamsters message  
    )  
    [custom_formdescriptiontype] => Array  
    (  
        [0] => hamsters desc  
    )  
    [custom_formnametype] => Array  
    (  
        [0] => Hamsters name  
    )  
    [_edit_last] => Array  
    (  
        [0] => 1  
    )  
    [_edit_lock] => Array  
    (  
        [0] => 1366738036:1  
    )  
    [custom_repeatable] => Array  
    (  
        [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:19:"hamsters repeat one";}  
    )  
)
```

How do I display the value `hamsters repeat one` only? Should I use print_r()? This is a wordpress issue as the multi-dimensional array is created using a wordpress function.

Comment: Have you seen [How do I retrieve multi-dimensional arrays from the wp_postmeta table, & display on a website?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95415/73)

Comment: How is this substantially different from your post that has already been closed today-- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96945/how-do-i-just-display-the-part-of-the-array-that-i-want-to ? I'd consider them duplicates. If you think the first post was closed unjustly, then edit it and it may get re-opened.